# Eclipse can't find -lprotobuf

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, mingw, protocol-buffers

I am currently trying to setup Google Protobuf for a C/C++ Environment.
In order to run, the Project requires the library "libprotobuf.lib", which I saved in "C:/CustomMods".
Now, when I am trying to compile my source code, "ld.exe" can't find the specified library. Here is my compile command (yes, I have added -L and -l)

```
g++ "-LC:\\CustomMods" -o CProtoc.exe "src\\address.pb.o" "src\\CProtoc.o" -lprotobuf 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lprotobuf
```

I am stuck on this one, would be glad if someone could help me out.

Best regards

Comment: I have used this wonderful tutorial to setup my protobuf: http://devblog.corditestudios.com/blog/2012/08/09/setting-up-protobuf/

Comment: `g++ "-LC:\\CustomMods"` should be `g++ -L"C:\\CustomMods"`

Comment: Thank you Praetorian for your ultra-fast answer, but unfortunately it didn't help. I changed the compilation command as you proposed to:
g++ -L"C:\\CustomMods" -o CProtoc.exe "src\\address.pb.o" "src\\CProtoc.o" -lprotobuf 

But I still get the same error!

Comment: I wasn't too sure that would work. I think the answer to your problem lies [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use). Use `-llibprotobuf` instead of `-lprotobuf`

Comment: Glad it helped, you should post an answer with what you've learned.